# Получение ссылки с location curl

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Server: uServ/1.5.4

Date: Wed, 04 Jul 2012 16:25:14 GMT

Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Connection: keep-alive

Keep-Alive: timeout=15

Set-Cookie: 4uquizuCoz=; path=/; expires=Mon, 05-Jul-2010 16:25:15 GMT; domain=.uquiz.3dn.ru;

Location: /stuff/tyu/bp/1-1-0-10

Cache-Control: private
```

Мне нужно получить в переменную `/stuff/tyu/bp/1-1-0-10. PHP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all( "/\\nLocation: (.*?)\\n/i", $text, $result );
var_dump( $result );
```

Comment: А зачем двойные обратные слеши поставили?

Comment: @Visman потому что за 3 года выработалась хорошая практика экранировать все, что должно быть экранировано. Тут можно получить ошибку, если решить усложнить регулярное выражение и воспользоваться многострочной записью регулярного выражения с флагом **x**.

Comment: Я бы пробел замениол на `\\s*`, на всякий случай.

Comment: @qwerty наверно Вы правы. Надо спецификацию почитать.