# Получение location из http_response_header

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как получить location из http_response_header? Пробовал использовать регулярные выражение на примере этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/124711/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-location-curl) но ничего не выходит.

Comment: А что у вас в результате выводит при выполнении кода из того ответа?

Comment: Исправил тот ответ. Пробуйте снова.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение сылки с location curl](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/124711/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-location-curl)

Comment: @ReinRaus сейчас получаю location таким методом: `$http_response_header[13]` и работает нормально, ваш способ выдает NULL. Но мой вариант не совсем мне подходит так как не всегда бывает location в массиве 13.

Comment: Если использовать регулярку из того ответа, то сперва нужно сделать `implode( "\n", $http_response_header )`

Comment: такой вариант `preg_match_all( "/\\nLocation: (.*?)\\n/i", implode( "\n", $http_response_header ), $url_result );` не пойдет?

Comment: Попробуйте функцию `$headers = get_headers($url, 1);` и ответ смотрите в `$headers['Location']`

Comment: Вопрос: Для чего вы используете значение из Location?

Comment: @Visman отправляю get запрос на сервер, получаю редирект(location)

Comment: Вам ReinRaus посоветовал поставить в его ответ вместо переменной `$text` конструкцию `implode( "\n", $http_response_header )` и `preg_match_all` можно заменить на `preg_match`.

Comment: @Visman отлично подошел ваш вариант, и сократил очень много кода. Большое спасибо! Добавьте как ответ, отмечу верным.

Comment: @ReinRaus вариант с implode возвращает массив с двумя элементами(`[0]"Location: URL" и [1]"URL"`).

Comment: Именно так и должно быть, потому что это регулярные выражения и сохраняемые группы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Копипаст из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.http.php):

```
file_get_contents("http://google.com/");

foreach ($http_response_header as $response) {

    /* Были ли мы переадресованы? */
    if (strtolower(substr($response, 0, 10)) == 'location: ') {

        /* Сохранить в $url адрес, куда нас переадресовали */
        $redirect_url = trim(substr($response, 10));
        echo $redirect_url;
    }

}
```